# Unwrap selected element Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html.

```
<span id="current" class="green unselctable" data-original-title="" title="">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
</span>
```

I'm selecting with with `$("#current")` but if I use the jQuery unwrap function the parent tag gets removed.

Is there any way to remove the span in JavaScript or jQuery without parsing the string and appending it to the dom?

**Edit**
I wanna keep the content of the div. I just want the tag removed.

Comment: So you want `Lorem...` to still exist?

Comment: Yup, all the html inside the selected element, without adding another wrapper

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can chain [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) into [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
$("#current").contents().unwrap();
```

`contents()` will return all the children of `#current`, including text nodes, and `unwrap()` can be applied to text nodes.

Comment: Very nice -- should be the selected answer

Comment: @vol7ron It will but in 9 minutes, thanks a lot to the both of you

Comment: In the [test](http://jsperf.com/unwrap-vs-replacewith) it seems as though replaceWith is faster, but for clarity, I think I like unwrap better.

Comment: hi Frédéric Hamidi, this solution leaves the unwrapped element as string. So the page displays the unwrapped html element as string. Can you please help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AbhayPS, I'm not sure I understand your comment. The unwrapped elements should take the place of their former parent and no string should be generated at all. Can you reproduce the issue in a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 4):

```
var $current = $('#current');
$current.replaceWith($current.text());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfsnX/) with the two current answers - pun?

[unwrap vs replaceWith](http://jsperf.com/unwrap-vs-replacewith)

Comment: My two cents: Questioner said `without parsing the string and appending it to the DOM`, and passing a string to `replaceWith()` does exactly that. Even then, using `html()` rather than `text()` might answer the question better (if the `<span>` ends up containing other elements). That said, your solution is probably faster than mine, yes :)

Comment: If you pull the textnode, is it really a parse? :) haha, but yes.  I think in both instances there may be copying/appending going on - I haven't looked at the jq source in a while, though

Answer (score -1):

Just hit this same question.  I think this might be marginally better...same effect but I think jQuery has to do less magic to make this work.

```
$("#current").replaceWith($("#current").contents());
```